# get data from variable table and return as datatable c#

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, parameterized

I need to get retrive all of the data from specified tables and I don't need the data to be strongly typed so I am returning it as a data table.

```
public DataTable GetByTypeName(String t)
    {
        var type = Type.GetType(t);

        var dt = new DataTable();

        using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MasterPlanConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            var sqlComm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM @table", sqlConn);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table", type.Name);

            sqlConn.Open();

            var dr = sqlComm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            dt.Load(dr);
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

When I run this I get the error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
Message=Must declare the table variable "@table".
```

I cannot figure out why this isn't working as I have declared @table. I know this method is open to some bad sql attacks so I plan to add in some protection about exactly what types can be queried against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct your query dynamically - (should be ok over here, but may expose your query to sql injection)

```
        var query = String.Fromat("Select * from [{0}]", type.Name);
        var sqlComm = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);
        /*sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table", type.Name);*/
```

Comment: +1 The way OP is trying will never work, because that's not how parameters work

Comment: Cheers, hopefully have mitigated sql injection by making sure that type has to implement a specific interface, worst case scenario you could view audit data for a different audit table than was specified