# SQL Return value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How do i return a table of a type. I want to return the table @Forums but i get an error Must declare scalar vaiable @Forums. My code return nothing after i imported a stored procedure function into my edmx

```
DECLARE @Forums Table
 (ForumGroup nvarchar(100), Title nvarchar(100), Description nvarchar(400), 
ThreadCount int, LastPostBy nvarchar(50), LastPostDate datetime, LastPostTtle nvarchar(100))
insert into @Forums
SELECT ForumGroup = (
    CASE WHEN ParentID IS NOT NULL THEN
        (SELECT Title FROM Forums WHERE ForumID = F.ParentID)           
    ELSE
        (SELECT Title FROM Forums WHERE ParentID IS NULL)
    END),
Title, Description, 
ThreadCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts P WHERE  P.ForumID = F.ForumID),
LastPostBy = (SELECT TOP 1 AddedBy FROM Posts P WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID ORDER BY P.PostID DESC), 
LastPostDate = (SELECT TOP 1 AddedDate FROM Posts P WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID ORDER BY P.PostID DESC),
LastPostTitle = (SELECT TOP 1 Title FROM Posts P WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID ORDER BY P.PostID DESC) 

FROM Forums F WHERE ParentID IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY Title
Return @Forums
```

C#:

```
public class Forums
{        
    public List<Forum> GetForums()
    {

        using (EntityConnection conn = new EntityConnection("name=CMSEntities"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            EntityCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "CMSEntities.sproc_Forums_GetForums";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            using (EntityDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
            {
                List<Forum> forums = new List<Forum>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Forum forum = new Forum(
                        1,
                        "",
                        DateTime.Now,
                        reader["Title"].ToString(),
                        reader["Description"].ToString(),
                        0,
                        false,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        true,
                        reader["ForumGroup"].ToString(),
                        1,
                        null,
                        DateTime.Now,
                        null);
                    forums.Add(forum);
                }
                return forums;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the C# code you're using to hit that SQL?

Comment: Are you defining the variable table in your C# code? If not, [this article](http://odetocode.com/code/365.aspx) makes it sound like it won't be in scope of your code. Maybe a temp table would be better?

Comment: How do you define a table in C# code

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986662/get-data-from-variable-table-and-return-as-datatable-c-sharp

Comment: That doesn't really help i still don't know whats wrong so if you can you please help me

Comment: My second comment tells you what is wrong... the variable table isn't in the scope of your query. Why use it at all? A view or stored proc sound like a better options.

Comment: This is a stored procedure and how do i get it in scope

Comment: I overlooked that in the question. [This](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=103383) is a good thread for that.

Comment: I just don't get it. tried output didn't work same error

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    ForumGroup = (
        CASE WHEN ParentID IS NOT NULL THEN
            (SELECT Title FROM Forums WHERE ForumID = F.ParentID)           
        ELSE
            (SELECT Title FROM Forums WHERE ParentID IS NULL)
        END),
    Title, 
    Description, 
    ThreadCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts P WHERE  P.ForumID = F.ForumID),
    LastPostBy = (SELECT TOP 1 AddedBy FROM Posts P WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID ORDER BY P.PostID DESC), 
    LastPostDate = (SELECT TOP 1 AddedDate FROM Posts P WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID ORDER BY P.PostID DESC),
    LastPostTitle = (SELECT TOP 1 Title FROM Posts P WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID ORDER BY P.PostID DESC) 

FROM Forums F WHERE ParentID IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY Title;
```

I don't see any reason you need a variable at all; you are selecting a combination of real and calculated columns which is legal.

For example, I could say `SELECT X = 1 FROM Forums;` The "X" column doesn't come from the Forums table, but it is valid.

If for some reason you do want to use the table variable:

```
SELECT * FROM @Forums;
```

Lastly, the error message you received indicates the cause of your original problem:

> Must declare scalar variable

A table is not a [scalar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_%28computing%29) value. The actual return value of a stored procedure must be scalar (obviously the stored procedure is allowed to `SELECT` any data it wants, but this is different from its return value).

Comment: After i imported my stored procedure into my edmx and i run the code nothing is returned

Comment: @KDM - if you run the stored procedure in SQL Management Studio, does it return data?

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a "table" from a stored procedure. The `RETURN` value can only be a single number (a scalar).

To return multiple rows from a stored procedure, you simply execute a `SELECT` that returns rows (as opposed to one that makes variable assignments). The rows from the `SELECT` are returned to the client in the form of a "result set", and are available from a reader.

So, to fix the code in your question, remove the table variable declaration, the `INSERT` statement and the `RETURN` statement, and just execute the `SELECT` call.

FWIW, you can also return multiple result sets from stored procedures, simply by executing multiple SELECTs that return rows.